# How to trigger an email sending

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am actually a newbie on Actions on Google & Dialogflow.
In order to improve my competences, I would like to trigger an email sending proposal on Google Assistant when the user ask to contact the support service.

The context is the following one:
[I am using Google Assistant answer on Dialogflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQKIK.png)

> User: "I would like to send an email to the support service."
>
> Bot:
>
> > Output vocal text: "Sure. On your Google Assistant, you would find a shortcut to send an email"
> >
> > Google Assistant interface: [*Shortcut that trigger a mail sending interface to the support service email address.*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxKAS.png) (It's like when you ask Google to send an email. It asks you to who and what message).

I also want to note that I have been on Actions on Google and Dialogflow documents, although I was able only to find documentation on email regarding Account Linking.

*Edit: I am not looking at all for code, just hints where I could find such information and if possible, how to use them correctly.*

Thanks a lot in advance,
I am really looking forward to improving my competences.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You will improve your competence a lot more quickly if you have a go yourself. SO exists to help users with specific problems, not write their code for them. If you get problems trying, then that is the time to ask on SO. See https://stackoverflow.co/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Sorry if you misunderstood me, I am not looking at all for code. Just hints about where I could find information regarding email sending trigger on Google Assistant & Dialogflow, and if possible, about how I could use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UX in [your screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxKAS.png) is not available within the context of an Action. Instead, you should use your conversation design to help users provide a support request and then send the email from your Dialogflow webhook.

For example, your conversation could guide the user through selecting a support topic and providing a summary of their issue, along with any account information they might need. You would then compose an email with this information and send it from your fulfillment webhook via SMTP or IMAP.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.

After few hours and tries with a webhook on the Fulfillment, I succeed by sending an email via SMTP, just like you said.
Thanks again.

Comment: @Lorkios can you please help, how you did this with the help of code or any example?